# How to change direction of Text in Xcode?

Tags: macos, formatting, format, xcode3.2

I want to type in Arabic in Xcode.
But I can't copy paste in the Xcode properly in right to left direction.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Xcode supports right-to-left scripts (to be honest, I'd be surprised if it did).

If you require string constants that contain Arabic text, you should probably store them in a `.strings` file and load them at runtime.